# A single line of 'code' or 'codes'?

Tags: difference, singular-vs-plural, uncountable-nouns, countability

What and why should I use, a single line of 'code' or 'codes'?

> Example sentence: Today we don't need to write a single line of codes
> to do anything

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Code" in the sense of "computer code" is a mass noun, and so has no plural.  It would be "lines of **code**".

> **code** .... *Computing* **mass noun** Program instructions. ‘*assembly code*’
> ...  ‘*The answer is 609,000 and this is the number of **lines of code** in the software for the computers and avionics systems.*’ (Lexico - https://www.lexico.com/definition/code )

Even among native speakers, non-programmers occasionally get this wrong:

> A former computer programmer at Goldman Sachs' Wall Street headquarters has been charged with stealing trade secrets by downloading sensitive computer codes
> (The Guardian - https://www.theguardian.com/business/2009/jul/06/golman-sachs-computer-codes-stolen )

In other senses (such as "code" meaning an encrypted system of communication or an encrypted message), it is a countable noun and can be pluralised as normal.

Comment: Leetspeakers write about 'teh c0dez'

Comment: In all probability, it was the source code that the former programmer was charged with downloading, not the opcodes.  And as for c0dez - people also refer humorously to the "internets" or "interwebz"... Sometimes things that aren't normally plural can be pluralised for humorous effect.

Comment: Executable computer programs are in machine code, and the instructions therein are opcodes (short for operation codes). Then there are ASCII codes, and so on and so on. A "line of codes" is meaningful, but unlikely in context

Comment: Granted.  As for the ASCII codes, they wouldn't fall within the definition of computer "code" that I adopted here (Lexico: "program instructions").